# Boot stuck at [ ok ] Staring enhanced syslogd : rsyslogd

Tags: boot, boot-issues, berryboot

I'm using berryboot to boot my first gen pi on an external hard drive, and even though it is better than an SD-card I seemed to have cut the power too many times and corrupting some files.

I don't get any kernel panics or such, actually the boot seems to go ok until it stays at

```
    [ ok ] Starting enhanced syslogd : rsyslogd.
```

where I've got a blinking cursor and I can see keyboard input at the screen (but not a prompt, it just displays whatever the keyboard types). It has even started one of my own installed programs that starts at boot.

I can access all linux files by connecting the hard drive to some other computer, so I wonder if anyone know a way to repair the installation? The image btw is raspbian_2013_05.

Comment: Same thing just happened to me. The only changes from a working machine was the following: `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install apache2; sudo reboot` Then it booted to the point of: `[ ok ] Starting enhanced syslogd : rsyslogd`. any ideas?

Comment: Nothing yet, but my installation has been going for 1-2 years. My guess is file corruption in both cases. My usual approach with raspberry pi is to re-install instead of fixing, usually saves time in the end. Since your answer is rather a comment, move it to a comment before admin sees you...

Comment: This is not the proper way to disable a service, but it is the easiest if you can't log in: Try moving `/etc/init.d/rsyslog` to `/etc/init.d/rsyslog.tmp`.  This will only work on raspbian wheezy but it sounds like that is what you have.  You should be able to get through boot now, then `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get upgrade`.  This requires an internet connection and may take a while if you haven't done it recently.  Afterward, move `/etc/init.d/rsyslog.tmp` back to `/etc/init.d/rsyslog` and try a reboot.

Comment: I am afraid that I had already wiped everything when you posted the comment, but it seems that it could have worked. Good anyways if someone else bumps this thread. user27538, did you have any luck?